Count and Highlight matching text in cts:near-query
I have requirement to count and highlight the matched terms, the below code counts OVER & LOAD as two different terms , whereas in near query(OVER NEAR/1[ordered] LOAD) this should be OVERLOAD(only one term which matched).
How can I achieve the matching terms as per near queries and not individual terms in near query?

let $bindings := map:new() 
                  => map:with("", 
                     function($operator, $values, $options) {
                       cts:word-query($values, ('wildcarded', 'case-insensitive'), 1)                       
               })
               
let $searchQuery := cts:parse($query,$bindings)

let $docs := 
    for $each in cts:search(fn:doc(),$searchQuery)      
    let $matchCount := fn:count(fn:distinct-values(cts:walk($each, $searchQuery, $cts:text)))
    return <count>{$matchCount}</count>

return $docs



You need to apply them as phrase search for which you should follow the following method Phrase search and highlighting with search:search in Marklogic.
